# Why all the underfull \hbox (badness) in the console, for this simple code?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption, badness, console

I'm getting lots of warnings in the console, about Underfull \hbox (badness ...), with several sub-figures settings.  Here's a MWE reproducing the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{figurename=Figure,margin=1cm,format=hang,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0cm,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={up}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]  % [ h ], [ b ], [ t ], [ p ]
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,justification=Centering}
    \subfloat[$\displaystyle{x = 5}$ ; $\displaystyle{y = 0,33}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{x = 1}$ ; $\displaystyle{y \approx 0,87}$. \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{\mathcal{J} \approx 1,75}$ ; $\displaystyle{\mathcal{K} \approx 0,95}$.]{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[$\displaystyle{x = 5}$ ; $\displaystyle{y = 0,40}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{x \approx 14,6}$ ; $\displaystyle{y \approx 0,13}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{\mathcal{J} \approx 2,18}$ ; $\displaystyle{\mathcal{K} \approx 0,98}$.]{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
    \newline
    \subfloat[$\displaystyle{x = 60}$ ; $\displaystyle{y = 0,036642}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{x \approx 3,78}$ ; $\displaystyle{y \approx 0,50}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{\mathcal{J} \approx 2,20}$ ; $\displaystyle{\mathcal{K} \approx 0,99}$.]{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[$\displaystyle{x = 60}$ ; $\displaystyle{y = 0,04}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{x \approx 4,99}$ ; $\displaystyle{y \approx 0,43}$.  \newline \medskip $\displaystyle{\mathcal{J} \approx 2,40}$ ; $\displaystyle{\mathcal{K} \approx 0,99}$.]{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
    }
    \caption[Blabla]{Some description.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with this code?  How can I fix all these badness?

Also, how can I rise a bit the **vertical space** between the two up figures and the two down figures?

Comment: Currently, your code isn't compilable since the `Raggedr2` package is missing.

Comment: If I copy your code and try to compile it on my sytem, I get an error message complaining about the `ragged2e` package not being loaded. Once I add that package, the code compiles for me.

Comment: I used the most recent version of `subfig` and `caption`.

Comment: What is the ragged2e package doing?  Never heard of this one.

Comment: It provides commands such as `\RaggedRight`, `\RaggedLeft` and `\Centering`. As opposed to the standard commands `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` and `\centering`, they also allow hyphenation. As mentioned before, I get an error message complaining about not having loaded the `ragged2e` package, since there is `justification=Centering` in the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would use an entirely different approach to position the images and the equations below them. In the following example, I used `minipages` in combination with `alinged` to also align the `=`and `\approx` below the images.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{figurename=Figure,margin=1cm,format=hang,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0cm,font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={up}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]  % [ h ], [ b ], [ t ], [ p ]

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\[\begin{aligned}
x           &= 5          &&; &y           &= 0,33       \\
x           &= 1          &&; &y           &\approx 0,87 \\
\mathcal{J} &\approx 1,75 &&; &\mathcal{K} &\approx 0,95
\end{aligned}\]
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}
\[\begin{aligned}
x           &= 5          &&; &y           &= 0,33       \\
x           &= 1          &&; &y           &\approx 0,87 \\
\mathcal{J} &\approx 1,75 &&; &\mathcal{K} &\approx 0,95
\end{aligned}\]
\end{minipage}
\medskip\medskip

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-c}
\[\begin{aligned}
x           &= 5          &&; &y           &= 0,33       \\
x           &= 1          &&; &y           &\approx 0,87 \\
\mathcal{J} &\approx 1,75 &&; &\mathcal{K} &\approx 0,95
\end{aligned}\]
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
\[\begin{aligned}
x           &= 5          &&; &y           &= 0,33       \\
x           &= 1          &&; &y           &\approx 0,87 \\
\mathcal{J} &\approx 1,75 &&; &\mathcal{K} &\approx 0,95
\end{aligned}\]
\end{minipage}
    \caption[Blabla]{Some description.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you change the vertical spacing between lines in your aligned environments?  Also, how to change the horizontal spacings between tabs in the same environments?

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get the following error message, issued by the `caption` package:

```
./main.tex:21: Package caption Error: Option `justification=Centering' requires
 the `ragged2e' package.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...labelformat=empty,justification=Centering}
```

You have two choices:

- Load the `ragged2e` package if you want to stick with `justification=Centering`
- Change `justification=Centering` to `justification=centering`

With either adjustment, your code will compile.

Incidentally, `\displaystyle` is a switch, i.e., it does *not* take an argument.